# Simple eigenvectors when eigenvalues are known

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am new and easily confused. I got a matrix, which I can find eigenvalue here:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2  
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So the eigenvalue for this is $2$.

However I am struggling to explain how to find eigenvectors, I am preparing for an exam so I need to get a step by step on how to get there.
I started by writing it in the form of $(A-\lambda I) = 0$.
By substitute $2 I$ got a new matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 -2 & 0 \\
0 & 2- 2  
\end{bmatrix}\;,
$$

which becomes

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0  
\end{bmatrix}\;.
$$

Then I am lost.

Comment: The eigenvectors are (nonzero) elements of the kernel (i.e. null space) of the matrix. So what vectors are in the kernel of the zero matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find nonzero vectors $v$ such that $(A-2I)v=0$. Since $A-2I$ is the zero matrix, you can choose any two nonzero linearly independent vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ and this equation will be satisfied.